# Auto-hiding top panel in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04, and I would like to auto-hide the top panel (the one that has date, time etc). I have followed [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/top-panel-auto-hide-ubuntu-20-04/?unapproved=3732481&moderation-hash=e78986883fd0e524f6f0d906e72080f5#comment-3732481) guide through all of the steps, but there was no change with the top panel behaviour. Could you please help me debug this problem? I will gladly provide system info required, please tell me what is needed

The following info may be of use

```
$ sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-prefs
chrome-gnome-shell is already the newest version (10.1-5).
gnome-shell-extension-prefs is already the newest version (42.2-0ubuntu0.2).
```

- Gnome extensions App opens, but there is no option to hide top bar as far as I can see
- On (Apt) Firefox, when opening the [extension url](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/), the following message is displayed

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host
> connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about
> installing connector.

**Edit**: The problem is now resolved. I needed to remove snap firefox and install apt firefox. I had originally done so using `snap remove firefox`, but apparently that was not enough. Running `sudo apt purge firefox` and redoing the whole process worked well

Comment: I don't use firefox myself, and don't really want to test this, but...  This is a question and answer site - I see that you have found a solution (which is great!) but you should formally enter your solution as an answer to your own question!  And then come back in a couple of days and *accept* the solution

Comment: Call me silly but I don't understand why a DM feature would involve a browser. What am I missing?